# pickling error in python?

Tags: python, pickle

I am getting this error, and I dont know what it means.  How can I fix this problem?

my code looks like this, I've used it before and it has worked:

```
parentdir = os.getcwd()
dirlist = os.listdir(parentdir)

for dir in dirlist:
    if not dir == "pubs_edits": continue
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(parentdir, dir)):
                        os.chdir(os.path.join(parentdir, dir))
                        file_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(parentdir, dir))
                        for f in file_list:
                            in1 = open(f, 'r')
                            dict2 = pickle.load(in1)
```

This is the error message:

```
    File "/home/md202/pmid_editor.py", line 18, in <module>
        dict2 = pickle.load(in1)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 1370, in load
        return Unpickler(file).load()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.5/pickle.py", line 858, in load
        dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: '\x00'
```

Comment: Full tacebacks please....is this your own code? How to reproduce?

Comment: What are you unpickling? If it's an instance of a class you defined, have you imported the class?

Comment: I am unpickling a dictionary that I pickled to a file.

Comment: what is the value of `in1`? Print it out to take a look. It looks like there may be some unicode characters in there that `Pickle` doesn't like

Comment: I don't have time to follow this clue, but this is exactly the error you get if you try to unpickle a unicode string, e.g. `s = pickle.dumps({1:2});  d=pickle.loads(unicode(s))`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to load all the contents of a directory, that might include a file which holds no pickled data.

Answer (score 13):

This exact error occurred for me when I tried to unpickle (using pickle.loads) a string representation that I had stored in a database via django. Django changed the charactee representation of my string so that `pickle.loads(mystring)` threw me that error. When I added an explicit string conversion in, it was fine: `pickle.loads( str(mystring) )`

EDIT: looking at the comments on the original post, I think this is related to the unicode string issue mentioned. I put a normal string into the database, and django gives me back a unicode string that produces this error.

Comment: Your answer just helped me with my problem.  I was using app engine and had stored the pickled string as a db.Text() property when I should have used db.Blob()

Comment: Thanks Matt, I have the exact error what you specified i tried to save it in db using Django and get this error while unpickling the object.

Comment: presumably this error would not occur on Python 3+?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, resulting in `KeyError: '\x1f'`.

In my case, if was pickled to a gzip file (ie: `gzip.open(fileName,'wb')`), and I was trying to read it with a normal file object (ie: `open(fileName,'rb')`).

Comment: It seems pickled files play tricky with gzip. My pickled file looked like a gzip (according to 'file') but when I tryed to gunzip it, it returned a tiny (from 200M to 10K) crippled file with no useful data in it (pickle.load gives then the same KeyError: '\x00' issue with such an unzipped file.

Comment: looks like the file is incomplete or corrupted. If it was pickled in a text format, you could have a look at `zcat myfile` - does it look reasonble?

Comment: It was probably corrupted, I tried regenerating it and I got no more errors when loading

Answer (score 2):

Pickle is binary so you have to read it as such. Instead of ('r') try using ('rb') read binary.  Also, if your writing the file ensure you are wrting the pickle file as binary as well ('wb'). That should work, hope it helps.

Comment: dunno why you are downvoted, this is the answer I was looking for.  an easy mistake to make!

Answer (score 1):

try

[pickle.loads()](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads)

Comment: For the life of me I can't understand why this fixed it for me.

Answer (score -2):

maybe you should try another protocol try `pickle.load(in1, 2)` !

Comment: Take a look at the module documentation [link](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format), the load function takes an optional parameter which defines how data is pickled .

Comment: According to the doc, load() takes no optional parameter, only dump does.