# dill: when loading stored object, getting `dispatch[key](self) KeyError: '\x7f'`

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I have been using `dill` ever since [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968685/pickle-yet-another-importerror-no-module-named-my-module) got answered very well by the package maintainer.

Recently however, in my use case, I am getting the following error:

```
stored_env = dill.load(f_in)
  File "A:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 250, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "A:\anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: '\x7f'
```

What might this mean?

I am using `dill` version: `'0.2.5'`, as retrieved by `pip install dill`

I tried setting `dill.detect.trace(True)`, but I get no output from that.

**EDIT:** Here's a minimal example that does not work:

```
#test.py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def my_fast_vector_add(x, y):
    num_elements = x.shape[0]
    z = np.zeros(num_elements, dtype=np.float64)

    for i in range(num_elements):
        z[i] = x[i] + y[i]

    return z  

class Environment():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.random.rand(10)
        self.y = np.random.rand(10)

    def my_vector_add(self):
        return my_fast_vector_add(self.x, self.y)
```

And the code that puts it all together:

```
#doit.py
import test
import dill
import os
import shutil
import gzip

env = test.Environment()
print "init add result: ", env.my_vector_add()
pkl_path = "test.pkl"

with open(pkl_path, 'w') as f:
    dill.dump(env, f)

compressed_path = "test.zip"

with open(pkl_path, 'r') as f_in, gzip.open(compressed_path, 'wb') as f_out:
    shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)

os.remove(pkl_path)

stored_env = None
with gzip.open(compressed_path, 'r') as f_in:
    stored_env = dill.load(f_in)
    print "loaded add result: ", stored_env.my_vector_add()
```

The error that is produced is:

```
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "A:/dill_issue/doit.py", line 25, in <module>
    stored_env = dill.load(f_in)
  File "A:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 250, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "A:\anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "A:\anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 886, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Comment: similar to your Q?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26350991/4646678

Comment: Might be some encoding issue, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11314602/4646678.  If so, I think `dill` is missing an `encoding` keyword.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns re: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26350991/4646678, it looks similar at first glance, but luckily I am making sure to unzip the file with gzip (`gzip.open`) instead of just using normal file open to read it?

Comment: @MikeMcKerns re: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11314602/4646678, not totally sure how that issue relates back to my problem, as I don't think I really understand what's going on here -- I am using Python 2.7 though

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I finally got a minimal example that produces an error close to what I am getting in my main body of code! In particular, what is needed is a reference to a numba decorated function `my_fast_vector_add` inside the class `test.Environment`

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Also, if you replace `dill` with `pickle` in the minimal example, everything works okay

Comment: @MikeMcKerns in particular, if the problem is with `dill.dump` (because if `pickle.dump` is used, then both `dill.load` and `pickle.load` are fine)

Comment: Your example works for me… both when I run from `doit.py` and also if instead I run from the interpreter.  I am using the latest version of `dill` (0.2.6.dev0 from github), `numpy` version 1.10.2, `numba` version 0.22.1, and python version 2..7.11 on a MacOSX.  Can you either give more versioning detail here, or fill out a ticket on the `dill` github page?

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I moved away from the problem for a bit, to work on some other issues, but now I am back here again. I don't get this error anymore, when using `dill` (0.2.6.dev0), but I am still having trouble...I think it's a different issue (even though it seems similar), so I'll write it up as a github issue

Comment: @MikeMcKerns posted a ticket here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the answer is to upgrade from `dill-0.2.5` to `dill-0.2.6.dev0`.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I am not totally sure if the new error I am getting is unrelated...it still has `dispatch[key]` bit...but just reads a little differently? See: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/158

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at the issue and address it directly.